# Play the chinese mp3 from assets folder in android

Tags: android

I have a chinese mp3 file and I want to play with `MediaPlayer` but it is not played in this. My code is like this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd=getAssets().openFd("music/formes/ZH/三角形.mp3");
mySound = new MediaPlayer();
mySound.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                            afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
mySound.prepare();
mySound.start();
```

The logcat out put is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: music/formes/ZH/三角形.mp3
```

Comment: just rename that file to another name and play

Comment: A Simple solution can be, just rename your file to an English name and then try again. It will 100% play.

Comment: But in my application i have more then 300 files so it is not easy to do that..Please if you have any other solution then please tell me to do that.

Comment: you have to to solve your issue

Comment: @DigveshPatel : Ok but its not solved by me that's why i put here..

Comment: plz rename atleat 1 file and play it i m 100 sure that is play

Comment: ya i know i tried that and its working but i have more then 300 files and its not the way to do that

Comment: ok then solve issue by your selves sry

Comment: @DigveshPatel : Oh..okzzzzz...:)

Comment: is any solution you found?

Comment: @DigveshPatel : No :(

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

String[] fileNames =getAssets().list("music/formes/ZH/");
for(String name:fileNames){
al.add(name);
     System.out.println(name);    
}

AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("music/formes/ZH/" + al[0]);
```

**And For Playing**

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
long end = descriptor.getLength();

player.setDataSource(this.descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
player.prepare();

player.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
player.start()
```

;

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: music/formes/ZH/-1

Comment: he just say just removechinise character from your file name

Comment: ya at that time its working i already told u..but in my project there are 500 music file and its like stupidity to change the file name..so please if you have any other solution then tell me to do that other then rename the name of the file